# Point second domain at website when only CloudFlare IPs have been white listed for first domain

Tags: dns, apache, ip-address, cdn

I blocked the IP address of my website because I'm using CloudFlare whose IPs I've white listed.

I have another domain which I want to point to my site. Besides an IP address is there anyway I can point this other domain to my websites fqdn?

Comment: Can you point the second domain to cloudflare as well?

Comment: Are you willing to use redirects?   Can your second domain 301 redirect to your site?

Comment: Yep i just went to domain registrar and forwarded to fqdn